# Is --help Flag A POSIX Standard/Recommendation?

Tags: posix

If I have an application that runs via a shell, is there POSIX documentation that says `--help` support is required? I would think so, as this seems to be a standard practice among the most popular terminal applications (GNU tools, etc).

I'm mostly curious if I can use the presence or lack of a "--help" option as a litmus test for finding POSIX-compliant/non-compliant commands.

Comment: Longopts were a GNU idea. Since POSIX only specifies `getopt` and not `getopt_long`, I'd guess `--help` is never part of the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX doesn't mandate `--help`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html

In fact, it seems that [POSIX guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02) suggest avoiding options that aren't a single character (though it's not prohibited, just a guideline):

> Guideline 3:
>       Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum character classification) from the portable character set. The
>   -W (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.
>
> ```
> Multi-digit options should not be allowed.
> ```

Comment: The reason it seems to indicate not using multi-character options is that they are supposed to be parsable by the posix `getopt()`, which doesn't take multi-character options

Comment: Interesting that `-h` is not mentioned either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing answer, that `--help` *is not* specified by POSIX/SUS.

However, if you are looking for any sort of standardization, [`--help`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dhelp.html) is included in the [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html).